# Static IP without a static IP

Tags: networking, ip, ipv4

I need my network to have an external facing IP address that is static. My ISP will not provide me with one.

I know I can use use DDNS to achieve this in a way. I want to setup an Exchange server and some other things onsite so I need an IP address really so i can set up MX records etc.

Is there anything i can use/do?

EDIT
I know about DDNS and no-ip etc. As i said i need to set MX records etc, i cannot put a DDNS/no-ip name in as a DNS can i ?

Comment: No. You are not in charge of your external IP address, your ISP is. DynDNS etc is your solution.

Comment: Change providers.

Comment: Are you sure your provider allows you to run a mail server? Seems very unlikely if they don't give you a static IP address.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT I know about DDNS and no-ip etc. As i said i need to set MX records etc, i cannot put a DDNS/no-ip name in as a DNS can i ?

Of course you can. There is nothing special about "DDNS/no-ip names", they're standard domain names, they're *already* in DNS, they hold standard A/AAAA records, just with lower TTL than usual.

Besides, MX records accept *only* names, you *can't* put your server's IP address in them anyway. So it doesn't technically matter what kind of IP address you have.

A better question is whether you *should* do that, if your provider is explicitly refusing to allow it.

Answer (score -1):

The way I have handled dynamic DNS has been through noip.com. They have a free tier where you can specify a subdomain on a few of their own domains and install a tool that will make sure your IP is always up to date with your subdomain. This way you could access your home network with .ddns.net or something similar.

You can also pay them about $30/year to migrate your own domain name and have them manage dynamic DNS on it.

There are also other services such as afraid.org that handle dynamic DNS, but I've found noip to be the most intuitive so far.

Comment: This question is not about dynamic DNS, so your answer does not solve the problem (probably the reason for your downvote)

Answer (score -1):

Let me explain what I am using:
I have registered to http://www.noip.com/
You can create a free dynamic dns that will resolve your ip address to a domain name if You want to access your pc across the internet. They also have a nice program that keeps refreshing the ip address associated to your domain name if You have a dynamic ip address. This must be running on your PC all time. I am using this for an ftp server.

You can use some port forwarding and/or [DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing))

EDIT:
Read this
https://serverfault.com/questions/445957/dynamic-ip-and-mx-record